# Regular expression for selecting trailing whitespace except first space after last character in line

Tags: regex

I'm editing text in Atom.
Beginning with the regex, `$\s` , I haven't been able to figure out how to anchor my selection from the *second* blank space *after* the line.

I want to remove the thousands of line returns in a text file ( originally formatted as an .srt video transcript ) and replace them with a single, blank space so as to not join together any words.

For example, my file looks like this:

```
This content is 

difficult to read

because the lines 

break after too 

few characters.
```

`$\s` will select *all* trailing whitespace, something that I don't want to do, because if I delete all the space selected by that regex then I will cause lots of words to join up into nonsense.

I want to start trimming the trailing whitespace of each line from the *second* blank space, not the first, so that the expected output would be:

"This content is difficult to read because the lines break after too many characters."

Instead of:

"This content isdifficult to readbecause the linesbreak after toofew characters."

Comment: Could you give an example of text?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Because `$` is a zero width assertion. With `(?m)$\s`, you only match the newline, or `\r`. You need something like `$[\r\n]+\s` with a multiline flag. Or even `$\R+\h` (if it is in Notepad++).

Comment: If you want to get all the text in a single line, then find `$\s+` and replace with a simple space ` `.

Comment: You did not provide an expected output. See https://regex101.com/r/pC0tR0/1 - does that yield the expected result?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , please see expected output, which is as you kindly described in that regex101 test. Although the Atom regex engine is not finding any matches with it.

Comment: Doesn't it work with `\s*$[\r\n]+\s`? That is a JS compatible regex.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , Atom v1.7.4 is not recognising it. The file is saved as plain text.

Comment: Did you check Regex option? Or did you try to replace in literal text mode?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew , Yes,  I have "use Regex" toggled on. Your solution, `/\s*$[\r\n]+\s/gm` , hasn't found any matches for some reason.

Comment: I did not say use `/\s*$[\r\n]+\s/gm`. I suggested `\s*$[\r\n]+\s`

Comment: @ WS , Also not working. Please note that those slashes and modifiers are included in the example shown at https://regex101.com/r/pC0tR0/1

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using MS Word's Find and Replace; substituting a single space ( by literally hitting the space bar once ) for all the hard returns ( enter `^p` in the Find field ).

I don't know why the Atom regex engine wasn't recognising the answer provided in the comments from regex101.com? It solves my problem in the regex101 tester.